# AWS Lambda unable to create Guice Injector

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to run a Spring Web project **(Java 8)** on AWS Lambda which is using **Google Guice(V4.0)** for injecting dependency.

I'm able to **run** using an `IDE IntelliJ` but when I implement a `RequestHandler` it is not able to initialize Google Guice dependency. Below is Lambda Handler

```
public class CoreLambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String>, String> {

    private final Injector injector;

    public CoreLambdaHandler() {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(newApplicationModule());
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String, String> input, Context context) {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

This results in the following error:

```
com.google.inject.internal.MessageProcessor visit
INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message: 

java.lang.NullPointerException
1) No implementation for java.lang.Integer annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=crawler.max.depth) was bound.
  while locating java.lang.Integer annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=crawler.max.depth)

2) No implementation for java.lang.Integer annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=crawler.max.pages) was bound.
  while locating java.lang.Integer annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=crawler.max.pages)
```

**Note** - I'm using Gradle `2.2.1` and building a fatJar using shadow Plugin to upload to `AWS Lambda`
The configuration on Lambda Console - **S3 path** and **Handler name** is correct - `com.aws.lambda.CoreLambdaHandler::handleRequest`

*Any suggestions or references are appreciated*

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you cannot instantiate an Injector inside the handler itself, there needs to be something else (a main method of sorts) which creates the injector and then actually injects dependencies.

The way I got around these issues was doing something like this:

```
public class CoreLambdaEntryPoint implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String>, String> {

    private final Injector injector;

    private CoreLambdaHandler handler;

    public CoreLambdaEntryPoint() {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new ApplicationModule());
        handler = injector.getInstance(CoreLambdaHandler.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String, String> input, Context context) {
        return handler.handleRequest(input);
    }


public class CoreLambdaHandler {

    public String handleRequest(Map<String, String> input) {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```